# Increasing number of axis tick with autoplot function (time series data)

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, data-visualization

How would we add model x-label ticks to time series plot (I am using autoplot function because "basic" ggplot needs a dataframe and with one columns time series data could have issues)

How to make more x label ticks with autoplot function

```
library(ggplot2)

library(gridExtra)

library(fpp2)

A <- autoplot(AirPassengers, colour = "#00AFBB", size = 1.1) +
  geom_smooth(aes(y = AirPassengers), method = "lm", colour = "#FC4E07", formula = y ~ x + I(x^2), show.legend = TRUE) + 
  ggtitle("Původní graf časové řady") + scale_x_continuous(breaks = round(seq(min(dat$x), max(dat$x), by = 0.5),1))

A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option by overriding the current x-axis:

```
autoplot(AirPassengers, colour = "#00AFBB", size = 1.1) +
  geom_smooth(aes(y = AirPassengers), method = "lm", colour = "#FC4E07", formula = y ~ x + I(x^2), show.legend = TRUE) + 
  ggtitle("Původní graf časové řady") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = scales::extended_breaks(10))
```

Here is another option by replacing the current breaks:

```
A <- autoplot(AirPassengers, colour = "#00AFBB", size = 1.1) +
  geom_smooth(aes(y = AirPassengers), method = "lm", colour = "#FC4E07", formula = y ~ x + I(x^2), show.legend = TRUE) + 
  ggtitle("Původní graf časové řady") 

A$scales$scales[[1]]$breaks <- scales::extended_breaks(10)
A
```

Note that ggplot internally also uses the `scales::extended_breaks()` function to calculate breaks. The 10 we put into that function is the desired amount of breaks, but some choices are made depending what are 'pretty' labels.

You could also provide your own function that takes in the limits of the scale and returns breaks, or you can provide pre-defined breaks in a vector.